# $@ expanding to wrong value

Tags: linux, gnu-make, autotools

Makefile:

```
TARGET = test/a_unit_test.cpp

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%_unit_test: CPPFLAGS += -DTESTS $($(@F:.o=)_includes)
%_unit_test: LDFLAGS += -lgmock_main -lpthread $($(@F:.o=)_libs)
%_unit_test: %_unit_test.o $$($$(@F)_objs)
    $(CXX) $^ $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

a_unit_test_includes = -I/usr/include/SDL2
a_unit_test_objs = test/b.o test/d.o test/c.o
```

test/b.o depends of "SDL.h" which is in /usr/include/SDL2 and make fails because that. After changing 'a_unit_test_includes' to 'b_includes', it runs fine. Why? I expected that '$@' expanded to 'a_unit_test', not 'b'.

[edit] To make the question clear, I'll give a example changing line 4 to "%_unit_test: CPPFLAGS += -DTESTS $(@F:.o=)_includes" and running "make -n".

Output:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 --coverage -DTESTS a_unit_test_includes  -c -o test/a_unit_test.o test/a_unit_test.cpp
cc  --coverage -DTESTS b_includes  -c -o test/b.o test/b.c
cc  --coverage -DTESTS d_includes  -c -o test/d.o test/d.c
cc  --coverage -DTESTS c_includes  -c -o test/c.o test/c.c
g++ test/a_unit_test.o test/b.o test/d.o test/c.o --coverage -DTESTS a_unit_test_includes -std=gnu++11 -lgmock -lgtest -lpthread --coverage -lgmock_main -lpthread  -o test/a_unit_test
```

My ideia of correct expansion was this:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 --coverage -DTESTS a_unit_test_includes  -c -o test/a_unit_test.o test/a_unit_test.cpp
cc  --coverage -DTESTS a_unit_test_includes  -c -o test/b.o test/b.c
cc  --coverage -DTESTS a_unit_test_includes  -c -o test/d.o test/d.c
cc  --coverage -DTESTS a_unit_test_includes  -c -o test/c.o test/c.c
g++ test/a_unit_test.o test/b.o test/d.o test/c.o --coverage -DTESTS a_unit_test_includes -std=gnu++11 -lgmock -lgtest -lpthread --coverage -lgmock_main -lpthread  -o test/a_unit_test
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I understand [secondary-expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html#Secondary-Expansion) right, you have to escape `$` in your prerequisite list. Maybe you have to do it for line 4 and 5, too?

Comment: @JojOatXGME I changed the question to put the output of "make -n" after removing one $ in line 4. I think the expansion is correct, but I don't understand which rule Gnu Make is applying...

Comment: It seems that make recompute the operations from line 4 and 5 for every target. The targets from the lines 2 - 4 in your output are called test/b.o, test/d.o and test/c.o. This may the reason why `$(@F)` is expanded to b.o, d.o and c.o. Currently I doesn't know a way to avoid this.